# Fragments Vs Single complex layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout

I'm still very much new to android development/java and I'm having a hard time understanding when Fragments should or shouldn't be used.

In the example image (below) on the Fragments docs on Googles site they use Fragments for two distinctly separate elements, a list and the content view.

I am trying to build a multi-paned layout but one in which each pane are closely linked. The closest example I could give is the stock Lollipop calculator, where you have the number pad pane and then the output pane above it. In such an example, should each of those elements be it's own fragment?
Or should it be a single fragment with separate elements to it (similar to how Fragment B in the example image has 2 windows in it)?

Thank you!

(http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#)
[image: Google Fragments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give more precise information about what you want to do.

For the Calculator, it's not based on panels, it's just simple layouts.

A tip to understand how the Calculator's or other App's layout is build you can use UI Automator Viewer, it's part of the Android SDK. Link :
C:\Users\your_session\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\uiautomatorviewer.bat
You need an android emulator or device in debug mode with it.

Comment: Thanks, I know I need to work on my question asking, apologies. 

But basically that's mostly what I needed to know - As a beginner I initially read the Android docs on Fragments to mean that any time you want multiple areas like that of the Calculator you use Fragments but I started to realise that's probably not true. Thanks for the UI Automator info too!

Comment: You're welcome, it's just layouts and child elements inside layouts and so for.

Comment: Thanks again. This is a slightly unrelated question but I'm hoping you won't mind me asking whilst you're here! It might be impossible to answer, I'm really not sure.

If I'm building something similar to the calculator app and build the layout like you say without fragments, how do I go about dividing up my code so it's not all inside Main Activity?
From my understanding I don't want to create extra Activities if it's all on the one screen but I wouldn't want to put all the calculation code in the Main Activity would I? I've tried putting it in generic java classes but I get errors on calling

Comment: This is more like a Java question related to _Object Oriented Programming_ concepts.

I'm trying to be superficial so that I give you a general idea but it's far larger than that and I recommend you first look for Java courses or tutorials, and then for design patterns.
You can find plenty with a Google search (try Android MVC Tutorial for instance).

The idea behind  is to divide you app into several packages with each responsible for one task, so you handle only the viewing in your activities, but the core code in other packages and classes.

You can post your code for help

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I understand it's not really how StackOverflow should be used.
I started learning pure JAVA for a while until I found myself getting too bored and made the jump to Android early. I've got the hang of a lot of things but my knowledge is still very patchy. It's good for me as I learn a lot faster/better jumping in but means I have to trouble people like yourself now and again to point me in the right direction, don't particularly like having to!
Will go do some homework.